# C# Create TreeView recursively from list

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

I currently have a list of items (Tuple) that have been generated programatically previously, that I am now trying to pass into a TreeView recursively, but am struggling a bit with getting it working correctly.

Example of the list: Name | Level

```
Fruits | 0
Apples | 1
Green Apples | 2
Golden Delicious | 3
Granny Smith | 3
Cox Orange Pipper | 2
Red Apples | 2
Pink Lady | 3
Red Delicious | 3
Oranges | 1
Blood | 2
Mandarins | 2
Vegetables | 0
Lettuce | 1
Iceberg | 2
Romain | 2
```

So my output wants to be:

```
Fruits (0)
- Apples (1)
-- Green Apples (2)
--- Granny Smith (3)
--- Golden Delicious (3)
-- Cox Orange Pipper(2)
-- Red Apples (2)
--- Pink Lady (3)
--- Red Delicious (3)
- Oranges (1)
-- Blood (2)
-- Mandarins (2)
Vegetables (0)
- Lettuce (1)
-- Iceberg (2)
-- Romain (2)
```

**Note:** Refer to the answer from LarsTech below for a perfectly fine working solution. Thank you!

I've stripped out erroneus code/attempts and I'll leave this all here for others who have the same problem.

Comment: what exactly is "LastNode" here? Is that the parent node? Also what does `roots.Add(tree.Nodes.Add("Items"))` do? Does Add return a new TreeNode?

Comment: Could you post the structure of your `TreeItem` `TreeNode` and `TreeView` classes?

Comment: Cleaned up the post a bit. The answer provided by LarsTech is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "level" value of each node is the only reference you have to the parent, so you can just keep a dictionary of levels to reference the last node used for that level:

```
Dictionary<int, TreeNode> lastParent = new Dictionary<int, TreeNode>();
foreach (Tuple<string, int> food in foods) {
  TreeNodeCollection items;
  if (food.Item2 == 0) {
    items = treeView1.Nodes;
  } else {
    items = lastParent[food.Item2 - 1].Nodes;
  }
  TreeNode treeNode = items.Add(food.Item1);
  if (lastParent.ContainsKey(food.Item2)) {
    lastParent[food.Item2] = treeNode;
  } else {
    lastParent.Add(food.Item2, treeNode);
  }
}
treeView1.ExpandAll();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is absolutely perfect and solves the problem with ease, I am most appreciative.